# How to set ImageView as background for any container?

Tags: android

I'm in need to set an `ImageView` as a `background` for a let's say `LinearLayout`. Is that possible to do so?

Comment: why do you need that.. kisu27's answer is the correct one.. but depending on your need there might be other solutions too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish you wrote more details about what you require. If this is only about setting an image background, you can use the `android:background` property of `LinearLayout`.  However, to answer your question directly, a view can be placed behind another using `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout>
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it should be possible. In the layout xml, try wrapping the ImageView inside the LinearLayout. Then in Activity OnCreate function set the xml as content layout.